# Conceptual question about calculation of moment of inertia of a rolling wheel

Tags: energy, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

[image: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iwAceuNDCl8]

In the problem above shouldn't  the moment  of inertia be $\frac{1}{2}mr^2+mr^2$ by the parallel axis theorem rather than $\frac{1}{2}mr^2$ since the instantaneous centre of rotation is the contact point at the ground? But the solution uses a value of $\frac{1}{2}mr^2$ for moment of inertia although the axis of rotation at any instant does not coincide with the center of mass.

The link to the video is https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iwAceuNDCl8

Comment: Because the center of rotation must have zero velocity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above question, they are analysing the situation from Centre of Mass. That's why they have taken the moment of inertia as $\frac{1}{2}mr^2$. However you can do the analysis from the instantaneous centre of rotation. The results obtained will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

They have solved the problem with respect to the center of mass(hence I=mr^2/2)as, though we know that there is friction acting on the system which is responsible for pure rolling it does not do any work because by definition of pure rolling the point remains instantaneously at rest. So while applying the work energy theorem we consider only the work done by the external applied force and the translational and rotational kinetic energy.

The concept of instantaneous axis of rotation tells us that we can assume it to instantaneously rotate about an axis passing through the point attached to the ground but then (1st case) the force would be responsible for a torque that you have to consider.